# Hats are not shown at all in Safari on macOS

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2017

I've just noticed that the hat on my profile picture on Stack Overflow isn't shown when I browse SO via Safari on macOS, while in Safari on iOS everything works fine.

Even more, on macOS I cannot even see the hats I earned. All I can see are some white boxes.

[image]

As you can see, the caption under the profile picture suggests the bird is wearing a hat, and yes, it is, because I've put it on myself, and it is shown normally on iOS, for example (even in 9.x). Yet it's not shown in Safari, as well as other hats.

System information:

- Safari 11.0.1 (13604.3.5)
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 (17B48)

Clearing caches doesn't change anything(

Comment: I don't have this problem on Safari 10.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: No repro on Safari 11.0.2 (12604.4.7.1.4) from Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: No repro on Safari 11.0.2 and High Sierra 10.13.2 beta. Are there any errors in the console or network tab?

Comment: Works for me on Safari Version 11.0.1 (11604.3.5.1.1)

Comment: You may have to disable a Safari Extension

Comment: You may updates your safari.

Comment: @Asif.Ali, it works for HighPerformanceMark with the same version of Safari, so the version of Safari may be irrelevant. Maybe caused by ISP, VPN, DNS server, etc. Or the Singapore mirror issue reported in another thread. Or a Safari Extension, as suggested by Brandon.

Comment: Works for me using Safari Version 11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.3) on Mac OS 10.13.2 (non-beta)

Comment: Please, use chrome for a while.

Comment: Use x to avoid y is battling symptoms, not the cause.

Comment: @jhonatan2760 I'd argue that {other browser} would be a better choice for Safari users. However, we'd all agree that Safari is the best replacement for Safari, being the most similar browser to Safari that there is.